# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 with http2 nginx proxy to java spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, http2

I run CapRover to enable https and domains on my java spring boot embedded tomcat server. This java application works on http2 to enable more SSE events.

## Runs fine without proxy

The application without CapRover/ nginx proxy runs fine (so when I access the ip:port on my server).

## Error when nginx proxy enabled

When I add an nginx proxy to enable https/domain on the application with CapRover, after a few minutes I receive this error in the console of the browser:

`NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER` in FireFox.
`net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200` in Chrome.

This error occurs on the SSE stream endpoints. BTW when loading the application I receive SSE events on those endpoints, so the endpoints do work. But there seems to be an error after certain period, maybe a timeout or something?

This is the nginx config I have:

```
events {
}
http {
    server {
        listen 443;
        location / {
            proxy_pass https://MY_IP_ADDRESS_COMES_HERE:7372; 
        }
    }
}
```

## CapRover directive `proxy_http_version 1.1;`

CapRover seems to add `proxy_http_version 1.1;`, and 2.0 is not supported, so what I want to achieve is probably not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

The proper directive is:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
```

And you should add the paths to SSL key and certificate by adding these directives:

```
ssl_certificate ...;
ssl_certificate_key ...;
```

Additional you need the following directives: proxy_ssl_server_name and proxy_ssl_verify. [See](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

Comment: I changed the config and got it running, but same error, but I think the problem is somewhere else. I read somewhere that setting this to 2.0, `proxy_http_version 1.1;` is not supported and therefor it does not seem to be going to work. This (version 1.1) is set by CapRover to enable sockets.

Comment: proxy_http_version is appeared in version 1.1.4 and still supported

Comment: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/923

Comment: If your backend server supported 1.0 or 1.1 version of http protocol you may use this directive http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version

Answer (score 1):

I came across something similar today, which may or may not be relevant to this. A server I manage runs nginx in front of tomcat and after updating nginx to 1.22.1 (from 1.22) and tomcat to 9.0.81 clients could not get css or js files served to them.

In Firefox the error in the network tab was NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER and the nginx error log was full of "upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream" messages.

Tomcat's HTTP connector had the compression flag set to "on", and turning it off fixed the problem. I don't know the exact mechanics of what was going on, but presumably nginx and tomcat were getting confused about what "content-length" meant when using compression.

No doubt there is a better way to synchronize the two servers' understanding of who's compressing what and how, but leaving compression to nginx doesn't seem like a problem in this case.